# Django complex QuerySet ManyToManyField with other ManyToManyField

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

Sorry for this title, I wasn't sure how to name it properly. I'm having problem with getting queryset of ManyToManyField that is in relation with other ManyToManyField. So it's look like this, there is model Company that has ManyToManyField with Person and Person model got ManyToManyField with Position, because logic behind it is that 1 company can have many persons and 1 person can have few positions and can be employed by few companies (which is clear I think). I'm getting the queryset for Person in Company by this way

```js
{% for team in brand.team.all %}
<p>{{ team.first_name }} {{ team.last_name }}</p>

<img class="img-thumbnail" src="/media/{{ team.photo }}">
<p>{{ team.position }} </p>
<p>{{ team.about }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

And I'm getting what I want, comparing this to template looks like this
[image]

but I'm not getting positions of person, only `company.Position.None` and I've no idea how to get this. From documentation so far I know that it works for single ManyToManyField but I couldn't find example similar to mine case and I'm not sure how I should get (person's position)

Below are my files

models.py

```js
from django.db import models
...

TYPES = (
        ('Startup', 'Startup'),
        ... )

CITIES = (
         ('Warszawa', 'Warszawa'),
         ... )

STACK = (
        ('PHP', 'PHP'),
        ... )

STUDENTS = (
  ('No', 'No'),
  ('Yes', 'Yes')
 )
STACK_ICONS = (
        ('/static/icons/stack/php.png', 'PHP'),
        ('/static/icons/stack/javascript.png', 'JavaScript'),
        ...
    )

POSITIONS = (
        ('CEO', 'Chief Executive Officer'),
        ('CTO', 'Chief Technology Officer'),
        ...
    )

# object position with relationship many to many to person

class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=POSITIONS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position

# object person relation many to one (many persons to one company)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, default=None)
    position = models.ManyToManyField('Position')
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

# object company

class Company(models.Model):
    # field person with relation many to one (many persons to 1 company)
    team = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField('Stack')
    website = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# object stack relation manytomany with Company

class Stack(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STACK)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=STACK_ICONS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```js
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
...

def brands(request, slug):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand})

def stacks(request):
    stack = get_object_or_404(Stack)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'stack': stack})

def positions(request):
    position = get_object_or_404(Position)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'position': position})

...
```

comp_view.html

```js
{% extends 'company/base.html' %}

    <div class="col col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-md-5 card-section">
        <div class="team ">
            <div class="card-title">
                <span>Team</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col col-md-4">
                    {% for team in brand.team.all %}
                    <p>{{ team.first_name }} {{ team.last_name }}</p>                        
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/media/{{ team.photo }}">
                    <p>{{ team.position }}</p>
                    <p>{{ team.about }} </p>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "single ManyToManyField". You have an m2m relationship, you need to iterate through it just like you do for the team members.

```
{% for position in team.position.all %}
  {{ position.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't give any result because you have wrote {{ position.name }} but model Position got only field position so when I changed it to {{ position.position }} now it works. Thank you anyway ! :D

Comment: Hi, can I ask you @Daniel about 1 more thing?

Comment: Open a new question.

Comment: Opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266583/django-foreign-key-many-to-one-relationship-displaying-on-template