# Django foreign-key many to one relationship displaying on template

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to display job offers that are in relation ship with Company (Many To One) but I'm not able to do it. I've tried many loops but I'm not even getting queryset so I must doing it wrong but can't solve what I'm doing wrong.

My files

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    # field person with relation many to one (many persons to 1 company)
    team = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    ...

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, choices=LEVELS)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=False)
    emp_type = models.ManyToManyField('Emp_type', blank=False)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

comp_list.html

```
            <div class="company-logo-container">
    <img class="company-logo" src="{{ brand.logo.url }}">
</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
       </li>
       <li class="list-group-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#social_media">Social Media</a>
       </li>
       <li class="list-group-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#offers">Job Offers</a>
       </li>
       {% for job in jobs %}
       {% for company in job.company.all %}

        {{ job.name }}

        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>
```

views.py

```
def brands(request, slug):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand})

def jobs(request, slug):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'company/job_view.html', {'job': job})
```

I've created few job offers and assigned them to 1 company but I'm not able to get them in company view so its look like the loop is wrong but I've tried so many loops and none results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are passing the company object from `brands` view to `comp_view.html` as `brand` template:

```
{% for job in brand.job_set.all %}
    {{ job.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Simply get the jobs for a company and then loop through them.

You can also get the jobs in view if you wish:

```
def brands(request, slug):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
    jobs = brand.job_set.all()
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand, 'jobs': jobs})
```

And then:

```
{% for job in jobs %}
    {{ job.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks man, yes I'm passing company object from brands as brand so it was my mistake that I was trying with job in jobs because they are passing to job_view.html now I understand :) THank you so much!

Comment: I didn't saw earlier this _set.all() so I will have to learn more about this (i'm new to django) but thank you for help :)

Comment: No problem, You can accept the answer if it answered your question correctly.